# systemd apparently not finding .service file

Tags: systemd

I've put together a foo.service file for our foo service that runs as a daemon.  The service runs fine when I run `systemctl start foo` (and `stop`) but 
`systemtcl enable foo` results in `Failed to issue method call: Invalid argument`.  The unit file is placed in `/etc/systemd/system/foo.service`, and has permissions 0755.  Setting systemd to debug and running enable gives

```
Looking for unit files in (highest priority first):`
    /etc/systemd/system
    /run/systemd/system
    /usr/local/lib/systemd/system
    /usr/lib/systemd/system
Looking for SysV init scripts in:
    /etc/rc.d/init.d
Looking for SysV rcN.d links in:
    /etc/rd.c
Failed to issue method call: Invalid argument
```

Googling around, it *seems* like systemctl isn't finding the .service file.  Is there any way to verify that?  If so, how can I fix that?  Any other ideas about what might be wrong?  Is there more debugging I can enable?  The debug info given doesn't really help me narrow down the problem.

foo.service looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Blah Blah Blah

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bar/doof/foo
Type=simple
PIDFile=/var/run/foo.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target,graphical.target
```

EDIT: Yes, I did run `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Comment: Have you ran `systemctl daemon-reload` after adding or changing your foo.service file ?

Comment: Yes, I did run daemon-reload

Answer (score 103, accepted):

For people from Google:

- Validate with `sudo systemd-analyze verify NAME.service`
- When using a symlink, make sure it uses absolute path
- Make sure the name is like `/etc/systemd/system/*.service`
- Do `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` after changes

Comment: For me, I was doing soft link (`ln -s ... ...`). I did hard link (`ln ... ...`) and it worked

Comment: @AnandUndavia You should be getting an error: `*.service is not a symlink, ignoring.` when using a hard link.

Comment: `sudo systemd-analyze verify xxx` gave me `Unknown operation 'verify'`

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY As of v248 it's still in the manual, but if you find the cause / workaround please edit it into the answer!

Comment: I got `Unit foo.service not found` when lookup the foo daemon, even when I specified the absolute path, would it be that it is recognised by the `systemctl` with another name?

Answer (score 28):

The issue in my case was the file was symlinked from **another partition** and [systemd do not support that.](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8307)

> Unit files have to reside on a partition that is mounted at the moment
> the host PID 1 is invoked. i.e. either on the root partition or some
> other partition that the initrd premounts.

*I'm answering to an old question because this is a top result while googling on the issue and might help someone*

Comment: Thanks. The worst thing is that no error is ever printed referring to this!

Answer (score 27):

I found this question over google, searching for "systemctl unit not found"

In my case I generated a *.service file via podman and no matter what I did, systemctl wouldn't find the service file.

Solution was to check selinux and set the correct labels. Example:

```
/sbin/restorecon -v /etc/systemd/system/container_httpd.service
```

Comment: Thank you! This did it for me. Can you elaborate what exactly it does?

Comment: good solution, indeed the podman generate is an issue

Comment: @Niwla23 Selinux restricts `systemd` to only seeing files labelled `systemd_unit_file_t`. The service file in question was created elsewhere (usually generated by `podman-generate`) and then moved here. Since moving a file does not update its label, this file keeps its original (different) label that was assigned when it was created, and therefore cannot be seen by `systemd`. `restorecon` resets the file context according to the persistent rules at `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files`, which "corrects" the label.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that if you are putting your units in the user folder `~/.config/systemd/user/*.service` that you are running the command as

```bash
systemd --user <command>
```

(note the `--user`)

Answer (score 4):

Error is because of two target are specified to `WantedBy`. Just mention in this way:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I really don't know how we can specify two targets to it.

Comment: Multiple targets are space delimited, not comma delimited.

Comment: WantedBy option may be used more than once, or a space-separated list of unit names may be given. So this answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue earlier when adding my own units, turned out to be wrong/missing context for SELinux. Test again with
`setenforce permissive` set  and set proper context for SELinux with `chcon` when in enforcing mode.

Comment: This solved the problem for me on Oracle OCI VM instance.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error when using Podman to generate systemd unit files.

The error occurred because selinux was blocking the file from being properly read. I found there were two solutions.

1. Set your directory to the systemd service location for unit files with `cd /etc/systemd/system`. Then use `podman generate` to create the file directly here. This seems to be accepted by selinux without issue.
2. Generate the systemd unit file with `podman generate` and copy the file to `/etc/systemd/system`. You then need to run `/sbin/restorecon -v /etc/systemd/system/container-<your container name>.service` to have selinux reset its security context for that file.

Answer (score 0):

When you run into this you can try to get the file it refers to. For example, I had the same problem with ContainerD. All I had to do was go to another server and get the file "cat /lib/systemd/system/containerd.service". Somewhere on your file system, this file has to exist (maybe in your backups).